# SQLite and Entity Framework configuration

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sqlite, configuration

Im currently trying to set up SQLite for database layer tests and im not getting how the config file should be written (wasnt able to find documentation for this). It seems that you duplicate configuration all over the file, sometimes people write the db factories into the entityframework section, sometimes only in the system.data section.

This is my current configuration file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="SWEChanContext" connectionString="Data Source=:memory:; New=True; Version=3" providerName="System.Data.SQLite" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <add name="SQLite Data Provider" invariant="System.Data.SQLite" description="SQLite" type="System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteFactory, System.Data.SQLite" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
</configuration>
```